# Geo Location not working for WebChromeClient on Huawei Devices

Tags: android, android-webview, android-location

I have a web app built using react embedded in a native app using WebChrome Client.

The react app tries to read your current geolocation using HTML5 Geo Location API and show results based on that.

It is working fine for most android devices but it is not working for certain Huawei phones in African Market because Google Play Services is missing from those devices.

While there is a way to get the geolocation of the device without Google Play Service by using Android Location Manager.

But the question is how do I configure WebChromeClient to use the Android Location Manager instead of Google Play Services?

I looked at the [WebChromeClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient) interface but found no way to do it.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Huawei [Location Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-locationkit/?ha_source=hms1) may help with your issue.

Location Kit provides capabilities for you to obtain the precise user device location quickly, helping you build up global positioning capabilities and expand your global business. Currently, Location Kit offers two modes for accessing its capabilities.

- [Android](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-introduction-0000001121930588) : The Location SDK for Android offers location-related APIs for your Android apps. These APIs mainly related to four functions: fused location, activity identification, geofence, and high-precision location. This mode is applicable to mobile phones and Huawei tablets.
- [REST API](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/server-introduction-0000001169867007) : REST APIs of Location Kit enable you to initiate requests using HTTPS to call location-related capabilities, including geofence and GeoLocation (API). This mode is applicable to web clients.

For Details, pls kindly refer [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/introduction-0000001050706106).

Huawei also has provided some HMS Core kit plugins for React Native:

[Reference documents](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/overview/HMS-Core-Plugin?ha_source=hms1)

[Location Kit plugins for React Native](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050142177)